# SharePoint 2013, Extract text from HTML and populate contact item in SP

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I’m usually a C++/C#/VB .Net/VBScript developer but I’m taking on a SharePoint project, expanding a bit. I’m familiar with Javascript but no expert.  I’m trying to extract text value from HTML so to be used to fill out a contact item in SharePoint 2013.  Below is the HTML code, wanting to extract name, title, company and then write back into my contact list in SharePoint 2013. I’m familiar with adding the code to the Content Part. If this is a duplicate post I'm very sorry.

```
<div id="profile-header-outer" class="profile-header">
    <div class="profile-header-general-info">
            <div class="profile-header-name">Firstname Lastname</div>
            <div class="profile-header-title">This person’s job title</div>
            <div class="profile-header-company">This person’s project</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also if I can pull the image name from the same HTML profile.

```
<div class="profile-photo">
    <img class='profile-image' src='/Photos/359/682/359682170.jpg?v=637287928728046239' alt='person-photo' onerror='this.src="/images/Avatar.png"' />

    <div id="abc-employee" class="profile-photo-text"></div>
</div>
```

The following is all I got so far.

```
<script src="/sites/vcet/SiteAssets/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>
$(function() {
var textToParse = $(`#profile-header-outer`).text();
$(`#output`).html(textToParse);
});
</script>
```

Any recommended books or sties on learning SharePoint 2013 developing with Javascript.
Any help is always greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the text from each node to get the contact properties and You may get the image name by getting the value from src attribute. If You already use jQuery You ma do it like this:

```
var generalInfoContener = $("#profile-header-outer .profile-header-general-info");
var name = $(generalInfoContener).find(".profile-header-name").text();
var title = $(generalInfoContener).find(".profile-header-title").text();
var company = $(generalInfoContener).find(".profile-header-company").text();
console.log(name, title, company);

var imageName = $(".profile-photo .profile-image").attr('src').split('?')[0];
console.log(imageName);
```

the result in console log should be as fallows:
[image]

hope this will be of any help